# Unable to Locate Installed deepxde Library Folder in C:/Users/Username/

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use the deepxde library. I used pip install deepxde, and it downloaded successfully. However, when I go to the folder "C:/Users/Username/", I can't find the deepxde folder. Please, can anyone help me?

I opened the command prompt and entered the command **pip install deepxde**. Afterwards, I expected to find the "deepxde" folder in "C:/Users/Username/."

Comment: Use `pip show deepxde` to see where it is installed.

Comment: Also, why would you expect to find it in that folder?